# Git log - How to list all commits that don't start with a specific word

Tags: git, git-bash

My main aim is to filter out all pull request merges thus in theory i would expect the following to work(it doesn't)

```
git log --grep="^!(Merge)"
```

Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you can't simply negate a word in a regexp by putting a bang in front of it (where did you find that?). You might have used [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that, but regular grep regexps do not support them. Using grep directly you can pass `-P` option to use much more powerful Perl regexps, but I didn't find similar option for git log.

Though, there is `--no-merges` option that will filter out all merge commits from the log:

```
git log --no-merges
```

Man page says that `--no-merges` means:

> Do not print commits with more than one parent

Answer (score 2):

That is not correct you ant use regex like that something like this would be better:

`git log | grep -o '^(Merge)'`

And this would provide more info:

`git log --pretty=format:'%h by %an, %ar, %s' | grep -o '^((?!Merge).)*$'`

I think you used ! To inverse it but the only known way of inverse revex search i know of is like above. Still the --no-merge would provide better info just writing for future referance

Comment: Unfortunately, that'll return only commit messages while `git log` itself can provide much more information.

Comment: Updated my answer but yours is still better just for future referance

Comment: thanks for the answer Learath2. Accepting KL-7's eventhough it's not exactly what I was looking for. Said that, it did the trick :D